# Checking if the curtain is open to click the checkbox

Tags: c#, selenium, checkbox, nunit

I use  `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(checkBox));` but i get this error

```
OpenQA.Selenium.JavaScriptException : javascript error: this.each is not a function

WebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
WebDriver.InternalExecute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
WebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
WebElement.get_Displayed()
<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<ElementToBeClickable>b__0(IWebDriver driver)
DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition, CancellationToken token)
DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
```

When I debug the code, everything works, so it feels like the checkbox becomes clickable before the curtain opens

Has anyone come across a similar error and know the solution?

Comment: Would you be able to provide more context around the curtain that you are referring to?

Looking at the error message, it suggests that it would be something to do with the construct of what you're waiting on (note the `this.each` is not a function message)